# No matching function call to class member

Tags: c++

I have implemented a generic list and I am trying to retrieve the data from a certain position in the list. umm... but I am getting an error: no matching function for call to 'List::retrieve(int&, Record&)'
Below is the code of main.cpp and a snippet of function retrieve from List.h.#include

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"    
#include "Key.h"
using namespace std;
typedef Key Record;
int main()
{
    int n;
    int p=3;
    List<int> the_list;
    Record data;
    cout<<"Enter the number of records to be stored. "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i=i++)
    {
    the_list.insert(i,i);
    }
    cout<<the_list.size();
    the_list.retrieve(p, data);
    cout<<"Record value: "<<data;
    return 0;
}
```

**List.h**

```
Error_code retrieve(int position, List_entry &x)const
    {
    if(empty()) return underflow;
    if(position<0 || position>count) return range_error;
    x=entry[position];
    return success;
    }
```

For full code:

Main.cpp: http://pastebin.com/UrBPzPvi

List.h: http://pastebin.com/7tcbSuQu

P.S I am just learning the basics and the code may not be perfect with regards to large scale reusable module. At this stage, it just needs to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`data`, which you are trying to pass as the second argument to `retrieve`, is of type `Record`.

The second parameter of `retrieve` is of type `List_entry`, not `Record`.

When the compiler says "no matching function," that usually means that it found a function with the name you used but one or more of the arguments that you are trying to pass to that function are of the wrong type or you are trying to pass the wrong number of arguments to the function.

Comment: ummm... Thanks. How should I modify the retrieve function of the list so that it can be used as I intended above in my post?

Comment: @user:  Change the type of the parameter or change the type of `data`?

Answer (score 2):

The error "No matching function for call [...]" usually means "I can't find a function that you can call with the following arguments."  It could mean many things - either you misspelled the function name, or the arguments are of the wrong type, or you're trying to call a non-const member function on a const object, etc.  Usually, the error will give you some more details about exactly what went wrong, including the functions it tried matching against, along with the types of the arguments that were actually found at the call site.  Templates can make this harder to read, but with a bit of time you can usually learn to read them.

In regards to this code, the retrieve function's second argument is of type List_entry, which is the template parameter to List.  In your main function, you instantiate a List, so List_entry is an int in this case.  However, you're trying to look up a Record, which (I assume) isn't an int.  If you either change the code to try looking up an int, or make your List a List, this problem should go away.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think Record is of type int. I have made Record an alias to class Key. If you could point out, here is the code for class Key. Key.h->  http://pastebin.com/zMVRj2Tr and Key.cpp -> http://pastebin.com/NuCyeBpj

Comment: Ah... notice that your Key class wraps up an integer (internally, that's how it's implemented), but at the end of the day it /isn't/ an integer.  It's a class, whose type is Key, that has a fundamentally different type from int.  You've defined an implicit conversions from ints to Keys (via your Key(int x = 0) constructor), but there's no way to convert from a Key to an int implicitly.  To make your code work, change the_list.retrieve(p, data); to read  the_list.retrieve(p, data.the_key());  This passes in the integer part of the key into the function, which should fix things.

Comment: I changed that to the_lsit.retrieve(p, data.the_key()); but I am still getting this error: no matching function for call to 'List<int>::retrieve(int&, int)'

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you're taking in the second parameter by reference, which means that you have to pass in an integer that's an lvalue (something you can assign to).  There really isn't an easy fix to this as long as you're keeping the List as a List<int>, because if you're storing ints then your retrieve function will require an int&.  This is probably a good time to change your List<int> to a List<Key> since, after all, that's really what you're using it for.  At a high level, a List<int> isn't a List<Key>.

Comment: Oh man! I have been stuck on this for long. Changing to List<Key> also gives similar errors. Here's the link to download the project (266KB)-> http://www.4shared.com/file/cAg_fgGA/SequentialSearch_2.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I'll be able to dig around/look at this now (fairly busy).  Sorry about that!  But I do wish you the best of luck with this - from what I've gathered this looks like it's probably a simple but subtle bug.